# How to make a function find a file through multiple directories?

Tags: php

Is there a "performant" way in PHP to search for a file through multiple directories?

Lets say I know that the file may be in one of the search paths:

$pathOne, $pathTwo, $pathThree. But now lets imagine, the user (developer who uses the framework) is able to group his stuff in subfolders as well. $pathTwo contains 20 subfolders, and each subfolder contains 2 more subfolders.

How could I search across all these paths plus subfolders for a $file? I've seen some frameworks using the file_exists() function excessively to do something like that (but without searching down the subfolders). Probably I would need a way to figure out which folders are there, and then step into them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) from the SPL library:

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator,
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    echo $file, "\n";
}
```

The above code will print out a list of all the files in the directory you specify, including all subdirectories.  You could alter the `foreach()` loop slightly to perform your file matching logic to find the file you are looking for, like this:

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator,
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $splFile) {
    if ($splFile->getBaseName() == $file) {
        echo "Found it";
        //do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Saves a lot of work of having to figure out all the files and directories yourself.

Comment: You can omit SELF_FIRST when you don't want directories and you could also make the check for the filename into a FilterIterator.

Comment: please, can you give an example? I can't get that to work that way.

Comment: @openfrog - The second block of code is a complete working example, and works fine if you just change the "/path" on the first line.  What kind of problem are you having?